How to draw vector on 3D surface
I have the function f(x,y)=2-x^2-y^2 , I wanted to draw the gradient vector and a unit vector (1/sqrt2, 1/sqrt2), at the point (1/2 , -1/2). The vectors should be plotted with the surface.
I tired plot3D to plot the surface and then used arrows from the tools to draw the vectors, but I felt like there is a correct and efficient way to do it.
What should i do?

Your function "f" is 2 dimensional. The gradient is also 2D. If you want to add this to the 3D plot "Plot3D" you need to add a third component.
Assuming the third component of the gradient is its norm and choosing an arbitrary third component of 1 for the 2D unit vector:{1/2,1/2,1}:
f[x_, y_] = 2 - x^2 - y^2;
g[x_, y_] = Grad[f[x, y], {x, y}];
p = {1, -1}/2;
grad = Append[g @@ p, Norm[g @@ p]]
p0 = Append[p, f @@ p]
p1 = {1/2, 1/2, 1}
d = 2;
Show[
 Plot3D[f[x, y], {x, -d, d}, {y, -d, d}, PlotRange -> {-6, 4}],
 Graphics3D[{Red, Arrow[{p0, p0 + grad}], Black, Arrow[{p0, p0 + p1}]}]
 ]


